# Form submit not working in safari and works in all other browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, submit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/fav_icon.png">

<script>    
function submitAlbum(){

     var frm=document.getElementById("custRegistration");
     frm.action="CustomerinfoServlet?formidentity=domobileappRegistrations";
     frm.submit();
}
</script>

</head>

<body style=" background-color:#f9f9f9" onload="DrawCaptcha();">

<!--start mainwrap-->
<div id="mainwrap">

<!--start midwrap-->
<div id="midwrap">

<div style="width: 100%; background-repeat:no-repeat; margin-top:15px; height:546px; background-image: url('images/form_background.png')">
<br/><br/><br/>
<div style="margin: 0 auto; background-color: #ffffff; opacity:0.9; border: 1px solid #D7EBFF; width: 400px; padding: 15px; height: 440px; margin-left: 56%;">

    <form class="form"  name ="custRegistration"  id="custRegistration"  onsubmit="return submitAlbum(this)" action="download.jsp" method="post" >

        <p class="name">
            <label for="name">Name <span style="color:red">*</span>:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="" pattern="[A-Za-z ]{3,20}" required/>
            &nbsp;<input type="hidden" id="formidentity" name="formidentity" value="domobileappRegistrations"/>
        </p>

        <p class="email">
            <label for="email">Email Id <span style="color:red">*</span>:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" pattern="((\w+\.)*\w+)@(\w+\.)+(com|org|net|us|info|biz|co)" required aria-required="true"  placeholder=""  required/>
        </p>

        <p class="submit">
             <label for="download" id="freetrail"></label> 
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </p>

    </form>
</div>
</div>

</div>

</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Above form is working fine in all the browsers except safari(version used is-5.1.7) and iPad.In safari the form is not validating the html5 required attribute and making the form to submit, while in other browsers(chrome,firefox,IE) its working fine.so can anyone tell me how can i make it done with safari??any help would be appreciated..

Comment: The HTML `required` shouldn't be your only validation, just a sidenote

Answer (score 1):

The HTML form validation is a [Working Draft](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#client-side-form-validation). 
It is a method of setting required fields and field types **without** requiring JavaScript.

Partial support in Safari refers **to lack of notice when form with required fields is attempted to be submitted**. Partial support in IE10 mobile refers **to lack of warning when blocking submission**.

Also support for using differently colored borders is not complete in Firefox or Opera - using a separate class for styling works well in both.

In Chrome the attribute `formnovalidate` doesn't work on `<input type="submit">` elements but does on `<button type="submit">` elements.

You can try to use the script bellow for all browsers not supporting HTML5 `required` attribute:

```
//Required attribute fallback
$('#form').submit(function() {
  if (!attributeSupported("required") || ($.browser.safari)) {
   //If required attribute is not supported or browser is Safari 
   //(Safari thinks that it has this attribute, but it does not work), 
   //then check all fields that has required attribute
   $("#form [required]").each(function(index) {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
     //If at least one required value is empty, then ask to fill all required fields.
     alert("Please fill all required fields.");
     return false;
    }
   });
  }
  return false; //This is a test form and I'm not going to submit it
});
```

**EDIT:**
As alternative, you can use the [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), in such basic way (more details on how-to use it are if you follow the link):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
// validate the form when it is submitted
$("#form").validate(); 
  });
```

This is the most browser's compatible solution.

Comment: The code above is jQuery < 1.9.x compatible, test it with jQuery 1.8.2 (because of use of `$.browser`)

Comment: ...or as alternative, include the `jQuery Migrate` plugin together with latest jQuery and the code.

Comment: @bodiO i tried with jquery 1.8.2 its showing the same result...if its working for you and if time permits you  can you please update my code in jsfiddle ???thanks in advance....

Comment: @bodiO thanks for the answers but sorry to say that i am getting the proper output..!!